# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have 3 entity classes

Ooline:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OolineId.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Ooline.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Ooline o")
public class Ooline implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="mitmas_mmcono" , referencedColumnName="mmcono"),
        @JoinColumn(name="mitmas_mmitno" , referencedColumnName="mmitno")
    })
    private Mitmas mitmas ;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="mitfac_m9cono", referencedColumnName="m9cono"),
        @JoinColumn(name="mitfac_m9itno", referencedColumnName="m9itno"),
        @JoinColumn(name="mitfac_m9faci", referencedColumnName="m9faci")
    })
    private Mitfac mitfac ;

    @Id
    private String obitno;
    @Id
    private BigDecimal obcono;
    @Id
    private String obfaci;

    private BigDecimal obabno;

    //getter and setters

}
```

Mitfac:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MitfacId.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Mitfac.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Mitfac m")
public class Mitfac implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mitfac",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ooline> oolineItem; 

    @Id
    private String m9itno;
    @Id
    private String m9faci;
    @Id
    private BigDecimal m9cono;

    private String m9acrf;

    private BigDecimal m9appr;

    //getter and setter

}
```

Mitmas:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MitmasId.class)
@NamedQuery(name="Mitmas.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Mitmas m")
public class Mitmas implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mitmas",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ooline> ooline; 

    @Id
    private String mmitno;
    @Id
    private BigDecimal mmcono;

    private BigDecimal mmaad0;

    private BigDecimal mmaad1;

    private String mmaccg;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

And following is my Repository file:

```
public interface OolineRepository extends JpaRepository<Ooline, String> 
{
    public static final String ORDER_LINE_QUERY = 
            "select x.obcono,x.oborno,x.obponr, x.obposx, x.obfaci, x.obitno, x.obitds, x.oborqt, "
            + "x.oborqa, x.obwhlo, x.obadid, x.obpopn, x.obrout, x.obmodl, x.oborst,"
            + " x.obnepr, x.obdwdz, x.obcodz, x.obpldt, x.obplhm,"
            + " x.obprrf, x.obspun, x.obrgdt, x.obrgtm, x.obwhsl from Ooline x "
            + "left join x.mitmas y  left join x.mitfac z "
            + "where x.obcono = :cono and x.oborno = :orno";

    @Query(ORDER_LINE_QUERY)
    public List<Ooline> getOolineLines(@Param("cono") BigDecimal cono, @Param("orno") String orno);
}
```

And the following persistense.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="tables">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>xxx.Mitmas</class>
        <class>xxx.Ooline</class>
        <class>xxx.Mitfac</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect" />

            <!-- These options seem intended to be developers tools and not to facilitate 
                any production level databases -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:as400://host/schema" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />

        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>
```

I am supposed to execute following query in SQL

```
"select x.oborno,x.obponr, x.obposx, x.obfaci, x.obitno, x.obitds, x.oborqt, x.oborqa,
x.obwhlo, x.obadid, x.obpopn, x.obrout, x.obmodl,x.oborst, x.obnepr, x.obdwdz, x.obcodz,
x.obpldt, x.obplhm,x.obprrf, x.obspun, x.obrgdt, x.obrgtm, x.obwhsl from Ooline x join
m3fdbdem.mitmas on mmcono = obcono and mmitno = obitno left join  m3fdbdem.mitfac on
m9cono = obcono and m9faci = obfaci and m9itno = obitno where obcono =1 and oborno = 'asasa'";
```

Can anyone verify if have constructed and mapped entity correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add property `mitfac` to `xxx.Mitmas` class.

Comment: it was a mistake from my side query constructed was not correct . now exception is gone . but query constructed is not working .   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement;